# Problem saving variables using PHP session

Tags: php, session

I seem to be having trouble saving session variables. I tried using `session_status()` and it outputs as 2. Maybe there's some way to check why session isn't saving properly?

Page1.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<body>
    <?php
        // Set session variables
        $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
        $_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
        echo "Session variables are set.";
    ?>
    <a href="Page2.php">Click Me</a>
</body>
```

Page2.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
?>
<body>

<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
?>

</body>
```

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 000webhost

Comment: Quite a few people having issues with sessions and 000webhost. The most common solution is to ensure you have a `/tmp` directory - https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/sessions-not-working/88329/10

Comment: @waterloomatt Thanks! That worked!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to add a tmp folder and add a `php_flag output_buffering on`